# Yii2: Rewrite URL without the help of a webserver

Tags: yii2

I would like to rewrite an URL purely using Yii2, without relying on a webserver (nginx/apache).

Example. I would like to "rewrite" a url such as `[POST|PUT|GET] /v2/book/author` into `[POST|PUT|GET] /v2/document/author`.

My first idea was to use [UrlManager](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager)'s [$rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$rules-detail), but those are not really rewriting the URLs, they map URLs into routes, so as soon as the first one matches, the chain terminates.
URL rewriting needs to happen before UrlManager even begins processing the routes.

My second idea was to create a custom [UrlNormalizer](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlnormalizer) which simply substitutes the incoming URLs. This sounds better, but I don't know if it will work.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What about simply creating rules that would point `/v2/book/*` routes to document controller? Why is terminating chain a problem when proper action is called?

Comment: @MichalHynčica Because both `/v2/book/*` and `/v2/document/*` urls need to work, and I have around 10 different rules for one, so with your approach I would now have 20. Furthermore they are dynamically generated by 3rd party modules. I need an elegant way where I can just create an alias without touching the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Urls are automatically created by Yii if you don't specify it.

By default `<module>/<controller>/<action>/<param>`

If you have a problem, where you would have to refactor the whole code for an url change, then yes, UrlManager it is. Url::to() uses your url config to adjust your `<controller>/<action>` identifier into an actual url. If you hardcoded the urls then you have to change the urls manually.

But you should be able to create to create a matching pattern to catch `v2/book/author`
I tried this in my code, and it worked:

[image]

So this should work as well

[image]

Comment: You are assuming I only have 1 rule. I have about 10 so with this approach I now need 20. Furthermore, they are dynamically generated by 3rd party modules that I have no control of.